# Excel IF AND statement with percentage output

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, statistics

I have a dataset of co-ordinates, except the co-ordinate is split into two column X and Y.

I'm trying to find the percentage of co-ordinates in a single quadrant, and thought IF/AND statements would work i.e.

```
IF "numbers in X Column is between -5 and 0" AND "numbers in Y is between -5 and 0" then display total as Percentage of all data
IF "numbers in X Column is between 0 and 5" AND "numbers in Y is between 0 and 5" then display total as Percentage of all data

Etc..
```

I think that may be the easiest way but I'm stuck on three things;

1. How to do it for negative numbers
2. How to do "is greater than a number BUT less than a number" (rather
   than just greater/less than), and
3. How to show results as a percentage (I only know how to return a
   TRUE or FALSE) i.e.:

```
=IF(AND(A2:A100>5,B2:B100>5),TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: So anywhere between 0 and 5 either positive or negative? Then check out absolute.

Comment: Can you post a data example? Maybe with the desired output?

Comment: Your puzzle looks easy to solve but need data example.  I cannot get your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version of Excel you can use `FILTER`.

For example, if you are looking for the percent of coordinates in Q1 (0<=X<=5, 0<=Y<=5), you can use something like:

```
=ROWS(
FILTER($A$2:$B$100, 
(($A$2:$A$100>=0)*($A$2:$A$100<=5)*($B$2:$B$100>=0)*($B$2:$B$100<=5))))/
ROWS($A$2:$A$100)
```

If not, then a simple way is to do what you were originally trying in a helper column, and divide the results by the total rows.

To answer your questions:

1. For negative numbers, e.g. Q3, just use negative numbers. Something like:
   `=IF(AND($A$2:$A$100>=-5, $A$2:$A$100<=0, $B$2:$B$100<=0, $B$2:$B$100>=-5),1, 0)`
2. Logically, it is not really "greater than a number BUT less than a number", but "greater than a number AND less than a number". The example in question 1 shows that in action.
3. To get as a percent, you add up all the values, and divide by the total. In an `IF` statement you can return anything (format is `=IF(test_is_true, value1, value2)`), so in the above example, I elect to return 1 for whenever a row meets our criteria.